# Debugging iPad Pro using MacBook

Tags: development, mobile-safari

We would like to test and debug problems with our website when it is viewed using the latest iPad Pro. Our development environment is entirely Windows.

We've got very close to being able to debug the iPad using this [webkit adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) on a Windows 10 machine but it is far from ideal. As a result we are considering investing in a Mac purely for debugging purposes.

Before we splash out on an expensive piece of kit please can I check that a MacBook is suitable for debugging an iPad Pro and if so would a MacBook Air do the job or would it need to be a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no requirement that you must use a "Pro" model in order to use the debugging tools in Safari. The MacBook Air has the exact same functionality. In fact there's no specific hardware requirement for this - it might as well be macOS running in a virtual machine on a computer running Windows.

Ofcourse there are other differences between the Pro and Air machines regarding performance, screen size, weight, etc.

Depending on your needs, you might be able to get by with renting a remote Mac online. Several services exists (Such as MacStadium) that allows you to rent Mac for a month or even by the hour. The Mac is accessed with remote desktop software. You could use remote USB software such as VirtualHere to access your iPad over USB from the remote Mac.

In order to do remote debugging of the web site on the iPad, you'll need to first enable it on the iPad:

- Open Settings => Safari => Advanced
- Toggle "Web Inspector" to on

Then plugin the iPad with a USB cable to the computer, and then do the following in Safari:

- Open the Safari menu => Preferences => Advanced
- Make sure "Show Develop menu in menu bar" is checked

Now you have the web inspector (what you call debugger) setup.

After opening your web site on the iPad, then open Safari on the computer and access the Develop menu. You'll find your iPad in the list, where you can choose your web site - the web inspector with debugger will be shown on the computer.

Comment: Many thanks for that JK, you confirmed what I hoped about it just needing to be macOS. Am I right in thinking there is no legal way to install macOS on a VM that is on a Windows machine?

Comment: That doesn't sound correct no. As far as I know, it's always legal to run macOS in a VM on top of Windows - as long as the Windows operating system is installed on a Mac. If you buy a license for macOS (by purchasing an old, used Mac for example) - you have legally obtained macOS. If you choose to run it on non-Mac hardware - that's not illegal, but it is probably breaking your EULA with Apple. I.e. not illegal - but breaking your agreement with Apple. This is not legal advice, so take it with a grain of salt - and contact a lawyer if you're serious.

Comment: @MikePoole I have added the suggestion that you could rent an online Mac for remote desktop access instead of buying your own. Would be a lot cheaper if you only have to do this once - some services even offer free trials.

Comment: Thanks for your replies JK, they are both very much appreciated (you Danes are a great people). As far as the VM is concerned I am not sure why we would VM on Mac hardware, we'd just install macOS on the mac it if we did but the issue we face is that we don't have any mac hardware. The remote desktop approach had not occurred to me so I'm going to see how feasible/costly that would be. Are there any things to watch out for in that approach?

Comment: Well, depends on your setup - number of employees etc. I.e. instead of buying a Mac for each developer, it might be cheaper to buy one Mac with virtual machines so that several employees could effectively share one Mac - each with their own virtual environment. Regarding remote desktop approach - I would take one of the services that offer a free 7-day trial and simply test out in advance. I think the main thing to watch out for is to choose a machine setup with macOS 10.14 - as far as I know, the most common USB sharing software has problems with 10.15 because of new security features.

Comment: many thanks again. That limit of macOS 10 seems a bit scarey. We've assessed all the options (including getting an Mac Mini) and the MacBook Air seems like the most cost effective way of doing it - especially given that it is about the same price as a years's subscription to MacStadium). We are only 5 developers and we can easily share the MacBook when we are need it for debugging and emulating.

Comment: Hmmm “emulating” - what do you mean by that exactly? I would probably have chosen differently than you, if you mean by that what I think you mean.

Comment: It was a secondary thought that I had but perhaps a red herring as I am not from an iOS development background. Our primary use of the mac would be to plug physical mac devices into it to debug using the inspector. It occurred that the MacBook could also have Xcode on it and perhaps I could use that emulator to view our site on devices we do not own. If we can't use the emulator to do this (i.e. it can only be used to emulate native iOS apps) that is okay but I thought it would be neat if we could view our site on an emulated device rather than relying on Chrome's responsive mode to do that.

Comment: Yes, you can use Xcode and the simulator for that. It’s not an emulator, but a simulator. However if you want to do this, and are thinking of maybe using it for app development - I think you’ll have a much better time with the Mac Mini rather than the MacBook Air

Comment: Thanks JK. We won't be using the Mac for native app development. All our app development will be PWA that we can code in the Windows environment. We did consider a Mac Mini but things like only having one HDMI out and taking up desk real estate seem to make the MacBook a better fit for us and the TCO seems lower. Thanks again for all your advice, it is much appreciated.

Comment: You can add up to 3 monitors to the Mac Mini using the HDMI and USB-C ports using simple cables. Just note that the Mac Mini base model has about twice as much CPU power than the Air.

Comment: Thanks JK, I saw that about the monitors. We don't have any fancy ports on our spare monitors and don't want to have to buy and mess with adapters so the MacBook Air seems like a simpler approach for us although I can completely understand why you would advocate the much better oomph of the Mac Mini. Our new Mac will probably spend 95% of the working week without being used so going to town on a desktop seems a bit much for us. We just wish it was possible to reliably debug an iPad using a PC like we can other with other mobile devices.

Comment: Well, HDMI and DisplayPort are not really “fancy” ports are not really fancy ports unless your monitors are really old  It seems you think the Mac Mini is more expensive than the MacBook Air - it’s really a lot cheaper.

Comment: I am not sure where I said that the Mac Mini is cheaper than the MacBook Air. I understand that the Mini is cheaper but when we add the peripherals and think about the need for deskspace it is more expensive and less flexible. We may well go for a Mini on performance grounds but it does not make sense for us in purely financial terms. Our spare monitors are not "really old" but they don't have the ports that the Mini requires. Thanks again for all your advice.

Comment: Well, you wrote it was the most cost effective, so I assume you meant it was the cheapest option. Peripherals is just any old USB keyboard and mouse and an old monitor. I think you have some really odd monitors if they haven’t got either HDMI, DisplayPort, DVI or VGA. Even the cheapest Dell Monitor at 79$ has DisplayPort. You can of course buy any computer you would like, just making sure you’re not making a choice based on misconceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the Dell monitor. As earlier indicated we might well still go for the Mac Mini (I would certainly like to) even though when factoring the cost of the workspace the MacBook is the more cost-effective. For the avoidance of doubt our spare monitors do have DVI and VGA ports.